# does Snap SVG have any similar feature to <animate attributeName="fill" from="white" to="black" fill="freeze">?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to do a fill transition using Snap similar to

```
<animate attributeName="fill" from="white" to="black" fill="freeze">
```

but cannot find anything about this online. Does Snap have any feature like this?

Comment: element.animate({fill: 'black'}), 1000);

Comment: I already tried that but it doesn't work.. see here https://jsfiddle.net/tzuya/3dfvtq4y/3/

Comment: That's a bug in 0.5.1, try the dev branch 0.5.2 or 0.4.0 or something. Eg https://jsfiddle.net/5rdeksf8/

Comment: Great, it works now. Thanks